# Ubuntu 20.04: where are launcher bar shortcuts store?

Tags: launcher, desktop-environments, shortcuts

Ubuntu 20.04 (or above): where are launcher bar shortcuts store?

This question specifically asks launcher bar's configuration store, not asking for Desktop shortcut or "application list" shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.
It is in DConf database: `/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps`
(`dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps`
Or open database with GUI dconf-editor.)
Value is an array of .desktop file names.